# Using NLog 2 with Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight-5.0, nlog

Has anyone ever used NLog 2 with SL5?

I cannot find DLLs for SL5 on the NLog homepage. When I try to reference the SL4 DLLs, VS 2010 says the following:

[image]

Why? I thought it is possible to reference SL4 DLLs in a SL5 project (but not the other way round)?

So I checked out NLog sources, opened its SL4 project, changed the target version from SL4 to SL5, Clean, Build and referenced the newly created DLL. While this seems to work it just doesn't feel right.

Any better ideas?

**Update:** Adding a reference to the original NLog 2 DLLs built for SL4 by directly editing the .csproj file of my SL5 project seems to do the job as well. I'm confused...

```
<Reference Include="NLog">
  <HintPath>..\Libraries\NLog\NLog.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Are you sure your referenced the **SL4** NLog assembly the first time and not for example the .NET Framework one? I used NuGet to reference the (SL4) *NLog.dll* from my SL5 application, and it worked without problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I referenced the SL4 NLog assembly. Just double checked it. However, this time I added it using the "Browse..." Button and not via the "Recent" list. Even though they apparently pointed to the exact same location, it now works. Sounds weird, I know... Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: i still cant use nlog with silverlight 5. care to explain how you make it work? i tried using nugget and nlog extended installation always fail. thanks.